# How to create Review apps on Heroku without connecting Github

Tags: github, heroku, devops, heroku-cli, heroku-pipelines

Before the Github - Heroku authentication issue saga happening on Heroku at the moment, I use pipelines to create review apps on Heroku. After my Github connections were disconnected from my pipelines on Heroku, I couldn't reconnect them so that I could continue using them to create review apps. How do I go about creating review apps in the pipelines?

Comment: After hours of researching, I found out that we can actually use [GitHub actions](https://github.com/features/actions) workflows to achieve the same feat. Here's [the link](https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2022/04/23/heroku-github-actions-pull-request/?msclkid=d17b60e6c55b11ec9851034a7a2f7816) to the post that helped me achieve that with GitHub actions workflow. The post explained in detail what we need to do to get a Review app in our pipeline.

Comment: I just figured out that we can also specify a buildpack for Heroku to build the app.

In the create app command in the [post](https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2022/04/23/heroku-github-actions-pull-request), I used this for my React app =>  `run: heroku apps:create ${{ env.HEROKU_APP_NAME }} --buildpack https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git`